# Use boundingRectWithSize with UITextView in a UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uitextview

Hello everyone I'm trying to expand my collectionView cell based on the text length of a UITextView.

To do this I decided to implement the method `boundingRectWithSize` but when I go to run the code my console always returns me a height of 0.

I can not understand where I'm wrong ... because the height is always 0?

```
-(CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(nonnull UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    SlideMenuCollectionViewCell *cell = (SlideMenuCollectionViewCell *)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    CGSize size = CGSizeMake(collectionView.frame.size.width, 1000);
    NSDictionary *attr = @{ NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12]};
    CGRect extimate = [cell.subtitleCell.text boundingRectWithSize:size options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin |NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading attributes:attr context:nil];

    NSLog(@"%f", extimate.size.height);

    return CGSizeMake(collectionView.frame.size.width, extimate.size.height);
}
```

---

My Consolle

```
2018-09-26 19:00:07.882366+0200[3676:1020208] 0.000000
2018-09-26 19:00:07.882556+0200[3676:1020208] 0.000000
2018-09-26 19:00:07.882657+0200[3676:1020208] 0.000000
2018-09-26 19:00:07.882742+0200[3676:1020208] 0.000000
```

Comment: Is `cell` non-nil? Is `cell.subtitleCell.text` non-nil? Does `size` have a non-zero width?

Comment: @rmaddy yes have a text inside it. NSMutableArray *subtitleItem = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                                    @"Hai",
                                    @"Se la tua email di registrazione non è piu in uso, modificala per aggiornare il tuo account e utilizzarla nei prossimi login",nil];

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. Run your code with the debugger. Step through this method and check those values and see what you get.

Comment: @rmaddy sorry maddy I do not understand what I have to do

Comment: You need to debug your code and make sure those variables have the value you think they do.

Comment: @rmaddy The textview does not contain the text that shows in cellForItemIndexPath ... because it displays first sizeForItemAtIndexPath then the rest

Comment: Instead of getting a cell in this layout method, just get the needed text from your data model.